# R foreach nested function not finding arguments to functions using do.call

Tags: r, function, foreach, arguments

I'm attempting to pull together an R package from many functions.  All work, including the top level one which involves foreach and do.call.  For some reason when I package them, it will not find the argument object for a function nested down at the third level.  This is the error I get

```
Error in { : task 2 failed - "object 'total.dose.params' not found"
```

I've put together a mwe at https://github.com/jamaas/qmradoparr.git

I've tried all manor of using .export and others but still can not get it to find this object.  In the repo is a very small R script called driver1.R that should demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to export any variable, you just need to pass each variable that is used by the `foreach` to its environment (to the function which calls `foreach`).

I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/jamaas/qmradoparr/pull/1) to your package.

Comment: Thx. This is a strange one, when I run it with your changes, it runs fine.  When I change the backend from doParallel to doMPI, it fails, can not find an object (one of the functions).  I saw something recently about using eval(call("function")) instead of do.call when inside a foreach loop and using mpi as backend, but can't find it now.

Comment: @JimMaas I don't know about that, sorry. I always use `doParallel`. Is there a reason why you absolutely want to use `doMPI`?

Comment: I do need it for a big Linux cluster, want to parallelize across ~ 400 cores on multiple nodes, which doMPI does nicely ... if it works!